# Live join several text files

Tags: linux, filesystems

I have plain text files `a.txt`, `b.txt` and `c.txt`

I would like a file called `big.txt` that is the product of concatenating a, b and c.

If I edited and appended to a, b or c, it would automatically update/append big.txt

How would I go about doing this on Linux/Unix?

Comment: Do you ever edit the big one, and if so, do you expect it to update the small ones too? That would make it tricky. If you only ever edit the small ones, you could probably just use `inotifywait` to watch a.txt, b.txt and c.txt and run `cat a.txt b.txt c.txt > big.txt` when they change.

Comment: having `big.txt` reflecting change of `a.txt`, `b.txt` and `c.txt` real-time, without intermediate operation looks to me as if you are expecting a filesystem driver.

Answer (score 2):

Break the problem into two parts:

1. Create the `big.txt` file when source files change
2. Run part #1 automatically when the source files change

Part #1 is a job for `make`, whose function is to create derived works from edits made to source files. In the example below, we say that "big.txt" depends upon "a.txt", "b.txt", and "c.txt". When we run `make`, the timestamps of the source files are compared to the timestamps of `big.txt` and, if newer, `big.txt` is made fresh:

```
$ ls        
Makefile
$ cat Makefile 
big.txt: a.txt b.txt c.txt
    cat a.txt b.txt c.txt > big.txt
a.txt:
b.txt:
c.txt:
$ touch {a,b,c}.txt   
$ make
cat a.txt b.txt c.txt > big.txt
$ make
make: `big.txt' is up to date.
$ echo 'hello world' > a.txt 
$ make
cat a.txt b.txt c.txt > big.txt
```

Now, after editing any of your files, type `make` and big.txt will be made *if needed*.

Part #2 can be accomplished in a couple of ways. The easiest is to run `make` in a loop in the background, like: `while :; do make; sleep 60; done &`. That's not particularly efficient, so you can use `iwaitnotify` to monitor the files for changes and then run make upon them. See [this answer for an example](https://superuser.com/a/181543).

---

An important note for `make` and `Makefile`: use *tabs* to indent. [This is an historical oddity of `make`.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2131213/2908724)